# $dialog MessageBox -- should autofocus primary button in angularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am facing a real hard problem to get the autofocus on primary button in AngularUI $dialog.messageBox so that when i hit ENTER key , messagebox close itself.

Any idea or workaround ??

Comment: No, do you have any solution?